# Why is my button creating a white screen?

Tags: android, button, webview, textview, android-tabhost

ok I'm running a tabhost app with a webview on each tab, each webview url ends with ?id= , on Tab 5 I have a textview and a button so that when the user types in a value it saves it and loads that value at the end of ?id=, however when i press my button currently it just opens up a blank white screen and makes my tab host disappear instead of reloading all of the tabs with a the new webview url. Why would it be opening up a new blank white screen?

Tab 5, with the text view and button

```
public class Tab5 extends Activity{

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab5);

    Button btnGo;
    btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    btnGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            Intent intent = new Intent(Tab5.this, Tab1.class);
            intent.putExtra("com.sideresult.outputapps.NAME", edit.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
                        }

                    });

}
```

Example of one of the webview tabs

```
public class Tab1 extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

public final static String URL = "outputapps.com/build/infoview.php?id=";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab1);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("com.sideresult.outputapps.Name");
    webView.loadUrl(Tab1.URL + name);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

}
```

Comment: In one activity, you have `com.sideresult.outputapps.NAME` and in the other you have `com.sideresult.outputapps.Name`. Try making them the same and see what happens.

Comment: @Patr3xion thanks for the catch, but it's still opening a blank white page, is there code that i am missing so that it refreshes all the tabs, instead of oping a blank white one?